# Android MediaPlayer.Create() returns null

Tags: android, wav, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an Android App that plays some sounds. For that I am creating an object of MediaPlayer. Below is the code:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testSound);
```

Here mp is null for Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10), i tried with other versions of Android (2.1, 2.2 etc.) it works fine. However with Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) MediaPlayer.create() call returns null.

The sound file (testSound.wav) is a wav file. I tried parsing the wav file to see if it is corrupted or not. It seems just fine.
Also, I could play this sound file using Windows Media Player.

Here's the testSound.wav file: [testSound.wav](http://www.filedropper.com/testsound)  and below is the code in detail:

```
public MediaPlayer mp;

// OnCreate() funciton
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testSound);
if(mp == null)   // mp is null for Android 2.3.3 on real device and on AVD both
  {
  Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not play sound",         
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  msg.show();
  }

//SetMediaFileToPlay() is called on Click event of button
void SetMediaFileToPlay() 
{       
    AssetFileDescriptor afd;     
    Resources res = getResources();
    Log.d("In SetMediaFileToPlay %s", g_strFocusedImage.toString());
    switch (g_strFocusedImage)
    {
      case RESID_ALPHA1:
      afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.ik);
      if(mp != null)
      {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),      
        afd.getLength());
      }  
      break;
      .........  //other cases
   }

 if(mp != null)
  {
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
  }
```

}

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Try creating new VM. If it doesn't work, please, provide us with more code.

Comment: Hello Vasily,

The problem is reproducible on Android 2.3.3 real device and AVD both. However it works fine on Android 2.2 real device and AVD. 

I have updated my question with code. Thank You.

Comment: Does 'SetMediaFileToPlay' work (assuming 'if(mp != null){...}' is executed)? Have you tried another file?

Comment: SetMediaFileToPlay() gets executed and a set of 10 to 12 files that includes testSound.wav fails (mp is null) on Android 2.3.3. This set of files work fine (mp is not null) on Android 2.2.
However, I played a random song file from my machine. It played successfully.

Comment: Try changing from testsound.wav to testsound.mp3.

Comment: Well, I'm still pretty sure that the problem is in your file, because MediaPlayer can play 16-bit WAVE files, but only if the format
type is PCM and not the extended format type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your file uses WAVE 8,000Hz MP3 8 kbit/s format, while android supports only 8- and 16-bit linear PCM: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html.

Try fixing your file.

Comment: #Vasily: Sorry for the late reply. Actually I couldn't get time to verify your observation/solution. Thanks I could see the file I am using is not a linear PCM file.Thank You.

Comment: How can I fix my file? Thanks so much!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia use free audio editors like Audacity. I believe VLC can also do the job https://www.vlchelp.com/convert-audio-format/

Comment: @VasilySochinsky Okay great! Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it with audocity. Do you think that could be the cause of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726927/do-certain-devices-have-different-audio-requirements) problem? Basically, the audio was working on my phone, but not my emulator? Thanks so much!

Comment: @VasilySochinsky Also, I have downloaded audocity. Do you suggest using `.wav`?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia it depends on your requirements, but .wav must be ok

Comment: @VasilySochinsky Okay thanks! I have liked your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that it returns `null` because the device doesn't support playing audio i.e `watch`.

To check if device supports MediaPlayer you can do a null check on `MediaPlayer.create()`

I found it on google [santa-tracker app](https://github.com/google/santa-tracker-android/blob/d773d54d20df936a2a8ea7987ac1c5dcdbfcf0e1/common/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/santatracker/AudioPlayer.kt#L30)

Answer (score 0):

`null` seems to be communicating that *something* went wrong. Since Google shows this as the first result for "android mediaplayer.create() returns null", my recommendation would be to go through your code and check

- if your device supports the format as indicated by Vasily
- if the file that you passed in actually exists or has already been created

In my case I had created an empty file before passing it to `Mediaplayer.create`. This worked fine on my emulated device, but crashed on my personal device.