# Null Pointer Exception When Trying To Play Sound On Button Click

Tags: android, audio, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer, android-button

I'm trying to develop an app that plays different drum sounds on button clicks.  With my current code, I'm given a null pointer exception when I attempt to click the button.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.pocketbeatbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer kick;
MediaPlayer snare;
MediaPlayer clap;
MediaPlayer openHat;
MediaPlayer closedHat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    kick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void playKick(View view) {
      kick.start();
      kick.release();
   };
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the method playKick is being called.  It could be that kick is null.

Comment: On the button view I have the onClick parameter set to playKick as shown: `android:onClick="playKick"`

Comment: Its because `kick` is `null`. Check that your resource is valid in `create()`

Comment: You may want to [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811466/android-mediaplayer-create-returns-null)

Comment: Thanks, @codeMagic ,it ended up being the format of the sound.  Though now, while I click the button it doesn't crash, the sound isn't being played.

Comment: I don't have much experience with `MediaPlayer` but wouldn't it be cause by calling `release()` directly after `start()`? I don't think you want to release the resources until after you are done with the `MediaPlayer`... Also, you should upvote the answer I linked to if it helped

Comment: Correct. `release()` literally releases resources and effectively stops the music.