# android - Short sounds on MediaPlayer throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, audio, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I have encountered a problem in which when ever I use

```
final MediaPlayer tick = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tick);
    tick.start();// tick is a short .mp3 file
```

in my app, no matter where, I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.a.aar.MainActivity.onClicks(MainActivity.java:123)
        at com.a.aar.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

But, whenever I use a slightly shorter sound effect, the app runs great.(I need a short sound because I want a lot of sounds coming fast and so the sounds will not stop)

What is the reason to this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: post where you set your tick's parameters

Comment: @user3793589 that's all code with anything to do with the "tick", even in onCreate it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Is this happening the very first time you launch the app and play an audio ?

Comment: @user3793589, yes, once I try to play it crashes immediately.

Comment: ook into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162230/how-do-i-play-an-mp3-in-the-res-raw-folder-of-my-android-app

Comment: @user3793589, tried, didn't work

Comment: Sorry, was about to send this instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811466/android-mediaplayer-create-returns-null

Comment: @user3793589 THANK YOU IT WORKS!

Comment: Welcome. Mark your question as answerd.